# Javascript function only working if PHP table contains numbers (no letters)

Tags: javascript, php

I adapted the following code for a project. The "updateTempDataClient.php simply INSERTS the selection into an SQL database. It works fine with one exception. If the table's first column has anything other than numbers in the field this function will not run.

```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
echo "<table border='2'>";
echo "<tr><th>ClientNum</th><th>Company</th><th>Address</th><th>City</th><th>State</th></tr>";


    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 


{
    $resultArray[] = $row;

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td onClick='selection(" . $row[0] . ")'><a href><font color=blue><u>" . $row[0] . "</a></font></u></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
        //echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
    //echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}


echo "</table>";

?>

<script>
function selection(myselection){

        $.post("updateTempDataClient.php?tabledata="+myselection,
            function(data){           


    }); 

}



</script>
```

Here is the INSERT query. The database has 3 columns. One is for id (int) the other 2 are client and vendor. Both are varchar(50). I tried adding an alert to the script. It will popup when a numbers only selection is made. However, if I click on anything with a letter in it the alert won't fire.

```
    <?php

$serverName = "palmbeach\sqlexpress";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"mylocaldb", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"******");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
    //echo "Connected OK.";
}else{
    echo "Connection fail.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


$test = urldecode($_GET[‘tabledata]);


$sql = "UPDATE TempData SET client='$test' WHERE id=1";



$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Close the connection.
sqlsrv_close( $conn );


?>
```

Comment: Sounds like its an integer column. Show the full code, where you execute the query - and the structure of your table. Otherwise we can't help you properly, we can only *guess*.